# how to find location of my firefox executable

Tags: find

Hi All: In some previous version of Ubuntu which I guess was 21.10, the location of my firefox executable was /usr/bin/firefox. Now, in 22.04, the location must have changed.
because I have a function browseURL that returns an error because usr/bin'/firefox is not found.

So, to try and remedy the error, I used "cheat find" to get help on how to use the find command to find the file but still no luck. Does anyone know the find command syntax that will look in all directories to find the executable file called "firefox". Thanks.

Comment: Try `which firefox`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. which firefox worked but the  link suggested type -a firefox which also worked. On my system, the command is in /snap/bin

Comment: Actually, the `firefox` you found is 'only' a link. You can use other commands or [this shellscript](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736432/how-to-get-the-location-of-a-program-in-ubuntu-terminal/1413975#1413975), to find out more details about various commands (snaps as well as other commands).

Comment: @sudodus: I'll check out the script. thanks a lot.